# Loading effect inside canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a game where a player can shoot enemies on hitting on the space bar I have a scenario that when the player hit space a loading bar should decreased till it hit 0 and then regenerate till it hit 100. When it regenerate the player can shoot again but I am having a problem in doing that scenario.

The code :

```
var charge=100
var player = {
        x: 225,
        y: 430,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        image: "",
        speed: 6,
        life: 3,
        middpoint: 25,
        playercanShoot: true,
        draw: function () {
            canvas.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        },
        shoot: function () {
            Bullets.push(playerBullets({ speed: 20, x: this.x + this.middpoint, y: this.y }));
            var x = setInterval(function () {
                charge = charge - 20;
            }, 500);
            if (charge == 0){
                clearInterval(x); // when the charge is 0 
               var y=setInterval(function(){
                charge=charge+20;
               },500);
            }
            if(charge==100)
             {
               this.playercanShoot=true;
             }
        }
    };
   function update() {
       if (keydown.space && player.playercanShoot){
                player.shoot();
                }

    }
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly that "Problem" is you are having in doing that scenario.

Comment: the charge is decreasing and increasing weirdly and i can't figure out the problem i guess it's in my setinterval functions

Comment: Please explain what exactly "decreasing and increasing weirdly" means.